# mysql can't change table or insert data into the table

Tags: mysql

I have made a table, but now when I try to change it I get the following error:

`#1025 - Error on rename of '<table name>' to '#sql2-532a-5eb06' (errno: -1)`

When I try google it only shows things related to foreign keys, which isn't the problem, seeing how there are no foreign keys to or from this table. I've also change the permision of the table, with out success. It also won't let me insert data into the table. So does anybody know what else it can be.

PS. there is nothing in the logs about this

*edit*
I've also tried recreating the table without success

Comment: create a backup, drop the table, try to create again. maybe.

Comment: Forgot to add that, but I've already tried that without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this

`DISABLE KEYS`

or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

make sure to

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

after you are done.

Comment: thanks SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; worked and the table continues to function as expected after SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; (can't accept the answer yet, apperently its to soon)